# <a4j:commandLink> - execute bean method

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have two rich:dataTables on one form:

**1]** List of items (last column contains a4j:commandLink according to [this tutorial](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&skin=blueSky))

**2]** Table depended on choosed row in the first table

Last column of first table:

```
<rich:column>
  <a4j:commandLink>
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/edit.png" alt="edit"/>
    <a4j:param value="#{it.index}" assignTo="#{myBdeCheck.currentIndex}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBdeCheck.editedWork}" value="#{bchItem}" />
  </a4j:commandLink>
</rich:column>
```

CommandButton in the facet of the second dataTable:

```
<h:commandButton id="btnCheck" action="#{myBdeCheck.edit}" value="#{conf.buttonEdit}"/>
```

At this moment I have to press a4j:commandLink (edit) and after that button on second form, and after that correct items are shown. But I'm doing one thing using two buttons.

How can I show the right items in the second datatable directly pressing a4j:commandLink?

(I tried to move `action="#{myBdeCheck.edit}"` to commandLink, but it doesn't work.)

Could you help me?

**UPDATE:** edit method:

```
public void edit()
{
  session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory('R').openSession();
  try 
  {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BDE.class);
    (some restrictions...)
    dataList = criteria.list();
  } catch {......}
}
```

**UPDATE:** part of rich:dataTable:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
  id="rich2"
  value="#{myBdeCheck.dataList}"
  var="bdeItem">

<rich:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="PersId" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.personalNum}"/>
</rich:column>
(.....)
```

Comment: you should be able to add that action to your a4j:commandLink. What happens when you try? Are there any validation errors? Richfaces 3.3 or 4.0? JSF 1.2 or 2.0?

Comment: Richfaces 4, JSF 2. Nothing is happening (adding action to commandLink), no errors. And the commandButton still works fine.

Comment: what does the method signature for edit look like?

Comment: I've updated my original post. But there isn't a problem I think, becaus this method called by commandButton works fine...

Comment: yeah. that looks fine too. if you add immediate="true" to the a4j:commandLink does it hit your action method? (this isn't a solution but would be helpful in debugging)

Comment: Still the same, nothing happens, no reaktion. I've updated my original post again and if i'm right, commandLink action should fill tha dataList and dataTable should show them. But even after refresh a page, data hasn't been shown and the selected row on first dataTable is lost. There is again selected the row which I've confirmed by last use of commandButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the Richfaces4 Component Guide:**

> The a4j:commandLink requires only
>   the value attribute to function. Use
>   the value attribute to specify the
>   text of the link.

Try adding a value attribute to the a4j:commandLink and then debug in the edit method and see if it is reached:

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Example Text" action="#{myBdeCheck.edit}" />
```

[Richfaces4 Component Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jcommandLink)

Also -- since you're wanting to use an image to submit would it be easier to switch to a4j:commandButton?

Comment: Thank you for help, your post led me to deeper think about a4j:commandLink, so I tried to replace him by h:commandLink and it works fine now :-)

Comment: No problem. Out of curiosity (and to help future searchers) did adding the value attribute work? did it hit your action method?

Comment: I didn't know how...? Value can't resolve method so I don't know which value to add. Maybe I didn't understand you well?

Comment: i updated the example with a code sample that adds the value attribute to the a4j:commandLink.

Comment: aha, it's still the same.. a4j:commandLink only set the params (currentIndex, editedWork) but not start the method

Comment: I've edit your answer and accept it (add h:commandLink). Thanks, Dave!